# Disabling native events for Remote WebDriver for Internet Explorer

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

How do I disable native events for Python Selenium Remote Webdriver and Internet Explorer?

Maybe relevant: I'm specifically trying to do automated testing using BrowserStack's Internet Explorer 9, 10.

Currently I build my remote webdriver thusly:

```
import webdriver

url = "https://%(username)s:%(automate_key)s@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub" % {
   'username': 'foo',
   'automate_key': 'fookey'
}
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER.copy()
capabilities['platform'] = "WINDOWS"
capabilities['version'] = "9"  # IE9
driver = webdriver.Remote(url, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but I believe you are looking for the `nativeEvents` capability:

```
capabilities['nativeEvents'] = False
```

Reference:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#read-write-capabilities